# I am searching for a match between a password and the rockyou.txt with php. It works just fine, but its horribly slow. How could I get it run faster?

Tags: php

**Hello,**

**I am searching for a match between a password and the rockyou.txt with php.
It works just fine, but its horribly slow.
How could I get it run faster?**

this is my code

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
$time_start1 = microtime(true);
$filename = "./rockyou.txt";
$file = fopen($filename, "r");
while (!feof($file)) {
    $line = fgets($file);
    $datas[] = $line;
   }
$time_end1 = microtime(true);
$time1 = $time_end1 - $time_start1;
$word = readline('password to test:');
$time_start2 = microtime(true);
$status = -1;
for ($i = 0;$i < count($datas);$i++) {
    $test = str_replace("\n", "", $datas[$i]);
    if ($word == $test) {
        $status = $i;
        break;
    }

}
$time_end2 = microtime(true);

$time2 = $time_end2 - $time_start2;
$time3 = $time1 + $time2;
echo $status . "||" . $time3;
?>
```

Any ideas of making it faster and/or less memory intense? Would hashing all the words help?

I am trying to create a simple password strength tester and thought that this is kind of essential part of that.

Comment: Might make more sense to put this data into a database, than you manually crawl your way through a text file every time.

Comment: It would speed things up if you check for the `word` as you read the file, rather than reading all the file into an array and then plodding through the array, but I have to agree with @CBroe a database would be a major improvement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you did your "is it the one" checks as part of the file read, rather than processing the whole file into an array and then processing that array the likelyhood is on average you would only have to process half the file once and not 1.5 times. And you woudl need only a fraction of the memory!

```
$t1 = microtime(true);

// get password to check
$word = readline('password to test:');
// read the monster password file
$filename = "./rockyou.txt";
$file = fopen($filename, "r");
while (!feof($file)) {
    $line = str_replace("\n", "", fgets($file));
    if ($word == $line) {
        $status = 1;
        break;   // stop the while loop
    }
}
fclose($file);

$t2 = microtime(true);
echo $status . "||" . $t2-$t1;
```